# Show CMS block only for customers who have not subscribed to a Newsletter

Tags: magento, newsletter, subscriber

I'm looking for a way to show a CMS block only to customers (who are logged in anyways) who have not subscribed for the newsletter.

Could someone help me with the code? I know how to implement the CMS block, just not sure how to check whether the customer has subscribed already or not.

Thanks a lot,
Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is  check a customer email exits or not by below code

```html
$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
 if($subscriber->getId())
 {
 if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
    // 'Confirmation request has been sent.';
 }
 else {
     //Thank you for your subscription;
 }
}
else{

//no subcription
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are logged-in and you have their email:

```
 $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
 if($subscriber->getId())
 {
      your code here 
 }
```